# Eggshell skull problems for superheroes

Tags: science-based, super-powers, medical

A common trope/world element of superhero settings is that the heroes and villains almost always use their "kid gloves" and avoid killing people as some sort of pact against mutual escalation.

For example, when Batman beats up some random mooks, he "does not kill" even though many of his victims will probably be crippled for life or at least spend a while in a hospital.

I'm wondering how realistic this is. Specifically, how many villains, heroes, goons, or civilians can a superpowered individual beat up before they statically kill someone by accident?

Comment: While the current answer is about as close to realistic that we are going to get, there are plenty of unknowns when it comes to super powers and super powered escalation. I personally think this is primarily opinion based due to that as anyone could argue that supers could prevent more deaths and that getting to building smashing levels would cause more deaths and both would be right depending on the story. TLDR VTC:OB

Answer (score 6):

#### About 1 in 10,000.

I'm going to assume that theres a parallel here between two types of people. I feel really awkward making it, but, here goes:

One who puts on their crime fighting outfit, wants to make the world a safer place, has a hidden identity, and has access to powers, weapons and tools normal citizens dont.

The other who... is the exact same thing. The comparison fits so well, right? I'm comparing superheroes to modern police forces.

(Hidden identity: masks and badge number I feel are similar, they allow partial anonymity, but not full. Batman gets his secret identidy blown all the time. 30+ Portland secret police recently got doxed.).

Were seeing months of unrest in the form on BLM protests now, and theyre spanning the globe, but I'm also remembering the opening scenes of "The Incredibles", where people were protesting damages caused by superheroes, and iirc politicians were getting pressure to basically "defund the supers" or something similar.

So googling says 10.3 million Americans got arrested in 2018. 1025 Americans died at the hands of law enforcement.

Now some of them were suicide by cop, some of them were legitimate self defense, some was police brutality, some were accidental. I'm going to claim that all of these count as "eggshell skull" deaths for our heros, as any death when you're super powered is killing someone weaker than you. A superhero may have someone suicidal attack him, or he may need to kill in self defense, he may misread a situation, he may underestimate his own strength, he may misidentify a harmless object as a gun and use deadly force, he may take things too far on adrenaline or rage, or he may attack an minority group disproportionately, or he may accidentally kill a perpetrator or bystander. Rough back of envelope maths say about 1 death in 10,000 apprehensions.

Now, American figures for police arrests are extremely high (prison capital of the world), and the death rate by police is also extremely high. I guess these sorta cancel out. Few places in Europe and asia I calculated from has lower rates of both, and it roughly cancels out; so 1 in 10,000 seems within an order of magnitude globally. Most superhero films are set in America, so it seems fair to use American stats for calculating an accidental death ratio.

Comment: If death rate by police is very high and arrests are very high, don't you have a much higher chance and thus more people getting killed by it? And not "canceling out"? Or is this calculated on the whole population and not per encounter of the police? It seems you measured from arrests for the American figures.